# Cannot find the interop type that matches the embedded type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook'. Are you missing an assembly reference?

Tags: .net, excel, vb.net, excel-interop

I'm currently writing a custom DLL to facilitate Java to HostExplorer interface. Apparently Java cant access the Host Explorer API directly or at least that's what I'm being told by the Java side, which is working fine. However I foolishly decided to include some Excel automation methods too and here is where I run into the problem.

The DLL compiles without any error but when I try to access certain elements of the Excel class I've written I get the following errors:

> - Cannot find the interop type that matches the embedded type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook'. Are you missing an assembly reference?
> - Cannot find the interop type that matches the embedded type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet'. Are you missing an assembly reference?"

This is the relevant code from the XL class:

```
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports System.Drawing
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop

Public Class XL
    Public XL As Excel.Application
    Public WBS As Excel.Workbooks
    Public WB As Excel._Workbook
    Public WSS As Excel.Worksheets
    Public WS As Excel._Worksheet

    Public Sub New(Optional ByVal WBN As String = "")
        XL = New Excel.Application()
        WBS = XL.Workbooks

        If WBN <> "" Then
            WB = WBS.Add(NameOf(WBN))
        Else
            WB = WBS.Add()
        End If

        WSS = WB.Worksheets
        WS = WSS(1)
    End Sub
End Class
```

This is then referenced and imported into a program I use for testing:

```
Imports HE_AUTO

Module Module1

    Sub main()

        Dim tso As New HE("TSO")
        tso.Read(1, 1, 1900)

        Dim output As New XL("test")
        output.WS.cells(1, 1).value = tso.HostStr

        Dim x As String = output.WS.cells(1, 1).value

        output.XLSaveAndClose(output.WB.name, "C:\", "testoutput.xlsx")

        Dim wb1 As Object = output.XLWBOpen("C:\", "testoutput.xlsx")

    End Sub

End Module
```

It is the **output.WS** and **output.WB** that give me the error.
Now I know that the simple solution is to add a reference to the Office Interop to my test program but as the DLL is to be used as an interface in Java this is not an option.

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Why the c# tag?

Comment: Please don't use "My 1st time here so please be gentle :) ", leave that to other sites.

Comment: You would have to create all your methods on the `XL` class and pass through the details. So instead of `output.WS.cells(1, 1).value = tso.HostStr` you would have `output.SetCells(tso.HostStr)` And on your `XL` class you would have the method `Public Sub SetCells(Byval value As String)` which would have the code `WS.cells(1, 1).Value = value`. _If that makes sense_

Comment: Thanks i get it now. spot on @Jinx88909